# Confirmation modal before script continues

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I'm using the following click event to trigger some ajax calls when a button is pressed on my page.

```
$('#products tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
      $.ajax({
          some ajax actions... 
      });
};
```

I would like to understant how to use a confirmation modal to confirm the execution of the script. Here is a dummy representation of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
$('#products tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {

      [[ Show confirmation modal ("do you want to continue?")
        if user clicks yes -> script continues
        if user clicks no -> script aborts ]]


      $.ajax({
          some ajax actions... 
      });
};
```

If the user clicks "yes" in the modal, the script continues and the ajax call is made
If the users clicks "cancel" in the modal, the rest of the script is aborted and the ajax call is not performed.

Any idea about how to implement this ?

thanks

Adam

Comment: You don't 'pause' the script. You just have an event handler for each button in the modal. The 'no' button closes the modal while the 'yes' button calls a function which performs the AJAX request for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you mention Window `confirm()` method by the "confirmation modal" this may give some idea:

```
$('#products tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
      const approve = confirm("do you want to continue?");
      if (approve) {
        $.ajax({
          some ajax actions... 
        });
      }
});
```